# jquery - trying to navigate to sections with a same link

Tags: jquery

I trying to navigate to sections. I want that every click on the fixed link /  the page scroll to next section. But its not work well. I can navigate only to first section. Whats wrong ?

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZbp7/74/)**

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {

      var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);

  }
});

$('.btn-red').click(function(e){
   //e.preventDefault();

   $('section').next().scrollTo(400, 'linear');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the jQuery documentation for .next() : http://api.jquery.com/next/

I think you should set a variable to hold the index of the "scrolled-to" section, and the increase it and scroll each time the button is clicked.

Let me know if you have any problem doing that.

good luck :)

Comment: I trying this:$('.btn-red').click(function(e){
   //e.preventDefault();
   var id_number = 1;
   var section = '#section-' + id_number;
   while ( count < 4 ) {
       $(section).scrollTo(400, 'linear');
        id_number ++;
    }        
});

but still don't work

Comment: `count` is not defined

Comment: You had some errors in your code, here is a new fiddle with some fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnrkv/

Answer (score 0):

Tryng it:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/BZbp7/108/


jQuery.fn.extend({
```

scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {

```
  var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
```

}
});

```
$('.btn-red').click(function(e){
   //e.preventDefault();
   var id_number = 1;
   while ( id_number <= 3 ) {
       $('#' + 1).scrollTo(400, 'linear');
        id_number ++;   
    }        
});
```